# Inline-block not adjusting width to child image

Tags: css

I have a horizontally scrolling container with several inline-block divs, each containing an image. The Image is set to height:100% and width:auto. The problem is the inline-blocks aren't taking the width of the image. They seem to be using the native image width rather than the rendered width.

```
.container {height:300px; overflow:auto; white-space:nowrap;}
.container div {display:inline-block; height:100%;}
img {height:100%; width:auto;}

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="example.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="example.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8mL0yx56/3/

The whole thing is inside a flex item, which seems to be what's causing it. Any way to stop this?

Comment: could you please create a fiddle showing us the problem

Comment: You haven't set a width anywhere. `auto` is default, which reverts to native.

Comment: @AndréDion - no it doesn't. An jpg `<img>` being a replaced element with intrinsic dimensions, will preserve its aspect ratio and set its used width based on its height.

Comment: @AndrewL Updated with fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
.flex-item {height:100%;}
```

It can solved you problem.

You set `.container {height:100%;}`, but its father,`.flex-item`, doesn't have height.

Comment: Yes, this looks like it. Although now there is now a little bit of space on the right of each image, do you know what this is? https://jsfiddle.net/8mL0yx56/4/

Comment: I guess that is caused by `box-sizing`, and I don't know the reason. But set `img { display: block; }` can fix the space issue. https://jsfiddle.net/mrfour/8mL0yx56/5/